# 301 redirect from classic ASP with parameter to ASP.net page on Volusion

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, response.redirect

I need to redirect 1000's of URL's of the following format:

http://egauges.com/vdo_mult3.asp?Type=Ammeter&Series=Vision&Units=E

to a new Volusion (unfortunately) ASP.net site with the format

egauges.com/Ammeters-s/22044.htm

Which is actually here for now (http://gnqvn.mzqlg.servertrust.com/Ammeters-s/22044.htm)

The old site will go away once this is working, so redirects must be done on the new site.

Volusion has a 301 redirect "tool", but unfortunately it can't handle anything after the ? in the original URL.  Volusion kicked it up the chain in their tech support, but says there isn't a way to do it.  I'm sure some sort of script, either server or client side, or maybe even something simpler would work, but despite searching high and low, I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Do the redirect directly in the asp site.

Change `vdo_mult3.asp` so that it redirects anyone who accesses it by using [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as follows:

```
 Response.Redirect("http://egauges.com/Ammeters-s/22044.htm")
```

You can also check the parameters passed to and change the redirect passed on those parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The old site will be going away, so the new URL will be http://eGauges.com/Ammeters-s/22044.htm  Since the old pages no longer exist the redirect will have to be done on the new site

Comment: @DaveF The web server should also be able to process classic asp requests. You just need one asp file to handle this.

Comment: @DaveF - make sure you new site will serve asp pages and place a file named vdo_mult3.asp with just the redirect line in it.  Then whenever anyone accesses the old URL they will be redirected to the new page

Comment: Just spent 3 hours with Volusion tech support. They are a "closed source" program, so I can't place ANYTHING in the root directory. I can place ASP files elsewhere, but they don't work either, and they don't support them!